# htaccess clean url not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having a lot of trouble with .htaccess, unable to get anything done really.

The site has urls that look like:

```
site.com/index.php?page=22
```

I would want it to look like

```
site.com/pages/22
```

or anything really. The important part is that if someone follows the

```
site.com/pages/22
```

They wlil see the content usually displayed by the non clean-url.
I have dozens of rules to write in that way, I will gladly do that part myself but on of the tutorials and rules I've read online did anything- at all!

A starting point would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job :

RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]

Comment: For some reason I'm not even able to save my htaccess file without having all the lines collapse into one big blurb..when everything is leagued against you :@

Comment: Ok I finally was able to get back to this and try what you suggested. It doesn't work, I get a 404 error. Any ideas?